# NGINX stream ssl_preread and vhost

Tags: nginx, ssl, nginx-reverse-proxy, stream

I try to configure a vhost for my vdi (citrix) configuration. The conf makes me crazy! I must use ssl_preread to get working.
Actually, my configuration of NGINX is made over CWP. I have a subdmain portal.xxx.net with a reverse to the citrix gateway, located in /etc/nginx/conf.d/vhosts/portal.xxx.conf.
When I add ssl_preread=on; I have error like: directive is not allowed here
After some research, I see that I must use "stream" directive. I add the stream configuration into the vhost configuration but same error: directive is not allowed here.
I see that I must add the stream conf outside the http conf, but i'm using a vhost... Cannot do it in the nginx.conf. I'm completly lost...

Thx for your help

Comment: Your post reads like a rant, not a description of a problem, the desired outcome, supporting evidence and analysis

Comment: Also, see [nginxconfig.io](https://nginxconfig.io) for all your nginx config needs. It's a tool by [Digital Ocean](https://digitalocean.com) that helps you customize `nginx.conf` for almost any case.

Answer (score 0):

To configure NGINX with `ssl_preread` for your Citrix setup, you need to use the `stream` directive in a separate context from your regular HTTP server blocks. `ssl_preread` is used within the `stream` context for TCP load balancing with SSL/TLS SNI (Server Name Indication) awareness. Here's how you can structure it:

- **Create a New Stream Configuration File:** Since you're using CWP and have your virtual hosts configured in `/etc/nginx/conf.d`, create a new file for your stream configuration, say `/etc/nginx/conf.d/stream.conf`.
- **Configure the Stream Block:** In this file, define a `stream` block and use `ssl_preread` within a `server` block inside it.
- **Link to Your Citrix Gateway:** Direct the traffic to your Citrix gateway based on the SNI.

Here's an example configuration:

```
stream {
    server {
        listen 443;
        ssl_preread on;

        # Use the SNI to route to the appropriate backend
        resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s; # Adjust the resolver as needed
        proxy_pass $ssl_preread_server_name:$server_port;

        # Additional configurations as needed
    }
}
```

Basically, you create a new configuration file in `/etc/nginx/conf.d` for the `stream` block, separate from your HTTP configurations. In this file, you define a `stream` server that listens on port 443, enables `ssl_preread`, and routes traffic based on SNI to your Citrix gateway.